# Apache Camel Hazelcast queue polling

Tags: configuration, apache-camel, client, hazelcast

This is a first time I am using Hazelcast distributed cache (queue) via apache camel. I created a route builder where I configured a `hazelcast-queue` endpoint as described in apache camel documentation. Camel route is started but it wasn't connecting to hazelcast (client configuration) instance. it was always starting new hazelcast (in build /embedded) from library.

I tried passing Hazelcast instance (client config) in route setter using hazel constants host, port, HazelcastInstance name, etc.., but all tries were unsuccessful.

- Step 1: I created spring bean for `HazelcastInstance` (Client network configuration)
- Step 2: Add all apache-camel dependency for Hazelcast
- Step 3: Created `RouteBuilder`
- Step 4: Override configure method and implemented the following line

Sample code

```java
fromF("hazelcast-%sfoo?queueConsumerMode=Poll", HazelcastConstants.QUEUE_PREFIX)
    .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.INSTANCE_HOST, constant("127.0.0.1"))
    .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.INSTANCE_PORT, constant(5701))
    .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.HAZELCAST_INSTANCE_NAME_PARAM, constant("hazelcastinstance"))
    .log("::>: Camel log " + body());
```

Camel started and listening [10.67.113.160]:5701 instead [127.0.0.1]:5701.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a running Hazelcast cluster, what you want to achieve can be done with Spring Boot by following the next steps:

##### 1. Add the dependency `camel-hazelcast-starter` to your project

With maven, you would add the next dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-hazelcast-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

##### 2. Create your specific `HazelcastInstance`

In the example below, it creates a bean called `customHazelcastConfig` of type `HazelcastInstance` built from the client configuration file `custom-client-hazelcast-config.xml` that has been added to the root of the classpath.

```
@Component
public class HazelcastConfigProvider {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance customHazelcastConfig() {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(
            new ClientClasspathXmlConfig("custom-client-hazelcast-config.xml")
        );
    }
}
```

##### 3. Specify your `HazelcastInstance` to your Camel endpoint

In the example below, we indicate `camel-hazelcast` to retrieve the `HazelcastInstance` from the registry using `customHazelcastConfig` as name corresponding to our specific instance created in step #2.

```
fromF(
 "hazelcast-%sfoo?queueConsumerMode=Poll&hazelcastInstance=#customHazelcastConfig",
  HazelcastConstants.QUEUE_PREFIX
).log("Receiving: ${body}");
```

##### 4. Switch in client mode (Optional)

By default the component `camel-hazelcast` is in `node` mode or cluster mode. To switch in client mode simply add `camel.component.hazelcast-queue.hazelcast-mode=client` to your `application.properties`

*This step is optional and could be skipped*

---

More details can be found from https://camel.apache.org/components/next/hazelcast-queue-component.html

Comment: It worked..Thanks a lot Nicolas Filotto :-)